# How to read local file in ios devices by using XmlHttpRequest in expo?

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, expo, firebase-storage

I've been dealing with this problem for 3 days. Here is the thing, in iOS I cannot read file by using `XmlHttpRequest`. My code is from expo's firebase-storage-upload-example ([link](https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/blob/master/App.js#L179)). I've added this code to my app.json:

```
 {
   "expo": {
     ...somestuf
     "ios": {
       "infoPlist": {
          "NSFaceIDUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes on event tickets.",
          "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
            "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
          }
      }
     }
 }
```

In android everything works fine. In iOS I think it's a permission kinda issue but I'm not sure. Here is the code and error:

```
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = () => {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = (e) => {
          console.log(e);
          updateStorageLoader({ error: e, loading: false });
          reject(new TypeError('Network Request Failed!'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
      });
```

Error: `Network Request Failed!`.
How can I resolve this? `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, options)` this method is not an option because it's not working with firebase storage upload.

**Edit:**
I think that it's not an issue with permissions. I've downloaded the latest example of expo firebase upload file, which is working totally fine on newly created managed worklflow app with 0 configuration. So I'm open to any hint instead of direct answer as well. Just if you could point out that something I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Buffer package mentioned [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/blob-stopped-working-in-expo-sdk-39/43516/7?u=simoncar) works as a replacement for XMLHttpRequest when posting to firebase storage.

Here is the code I used to get with-firebase-storage-upload working for 2nd and subsequent uploads

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer"; // get this via: npm install buffer
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
```

...

```html
async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {

    const options = { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 };
    const base64Response = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(
        uri,
        options,
    );

    const blob = Buffer.from(base64Response, "base64");

    const ref = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child(uuid.v4());
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your answer! This works for iOS but this time, in android it doesn't upload the files, or to be more specific larger files. However, in Android if I switch this implementation that you provide to the XHR request, everything works perfectly. So do you know why it's not working for android? In addition, do you know why we are getting network error for XHR in iOS?

Comment: Looks like the root problem is react-native version 0.63.2 and its fixed in 0.63.3. More detail about how expo is patching release 39 here https://forums.expo.io/t/blob-stopped-working-in-expo-sdk-39/43516/12

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing such info.