# expo-image-picker gives network request failed when i upload an image in ios but it works fine on android

Tags: ios, image, react-native, file-upload, expo

This is the code that i used to upload images on IOS

```js
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Image,
                    allowsEditing: true,
                    quality: 1,
                });
```

And in the output i got,

```
Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 2001,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///Users/sajid/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A48F2141-D9AF-457A-9D14-D2F2D4B6336B/data/Containers/Data/Application/803F58D8-0CF9-43CA-8972-599C460687B1/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540sajid_542%252FGoTrillo/ImagePicker/19952322-2D5E-495B-A4AF-427EA23663A6.jpg",
  "width": 3000,
}
```

Till this point it works fine, later when i call fetch on result.uri, it gives me following error on ios ,

```
const response = await fetch(result.uri);
```

Output Error: TypeError: Network request failed

This Error is not beinng raise on Android where as in IOS its giving this error when i use the above functions for the second time.Someone please sugggest a fix for this issue.

Comment: It's a bug in RN :)

Comment: It's also happening to me. Has anyone more information or workarounds? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after lots of search on google,

We need to replace file:// with /private for a fix in ios physical device.

[You can refer this link for extra inforamtion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29364#issuecomment-700777951)

Comment: How did you fix it because I still have the file:// and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I solved it with the following:

```
const localUri = result.uri;
const filename = localUri.split('/').pop();
const match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
const type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
const obj = { uri: localUri, name: filename, type };
```

And then you can use this **obj** to upload in the server using **FormData**.

Comment: Works for me, just change my implementation for this one and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another workaround for this problem while Expo Team handles patching the react native version. For iOS you can use this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142345/7987910) and for android regular XHR would be sufficient, detailed issue [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time. This is what I did.

Make sure you follow the amplify guide for setting up a app. amplify init, amplify add auth, amplify push, and then amplify add storage and then do this.

```
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './src/aws-exports'
// import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
// Might need to switch line 7 to awsconfig 
Amplify.configure(config)

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState('Evan Erickson')

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(result) 

    async function pathToImageFile(data) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(data);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await Storage.put(`customers/${name}`, blob, {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg', // contentType is optional
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading file:', err);
      }
    }
    // later
    pathToImageFile(result.uri);
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
      <Button title="Upload image" onPress={() => {alert(image)}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way using which u can solve this problem and its work for me as well.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10394#issuecomment-700509863

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

// Pick the photo
const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [1, 1]
});

// Fetch the photo with it's local URI
const file = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(pickerResult.uri, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
});

// Create a ref in Firebase (I'm using my user's ID)
const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`avatars/${user.uid}`);

// Upload Base64 image to Firebase
const snapshot = await ref.putString(file, 'base64');

// Create a download URL
const remoteURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

// Return the URL
return remoteURL;
```